# can't retrieve recent videos added to a playlist

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve list of videos of a playlist. However when I run my script after having added videos to that playlist, it's not taking the recent video into account.

When I run the script from IRB or even by a get request, I can get the new video. What am I missing in my ruby script?

```
require 'google/api_client'
    ...
    yt_channel_playlists_ids.each do |playlist|
playlistitems_response = client.execute :key => GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    :api_method => youtube.playlist_items.list,
    :parameters => 
    {:playlistId => playlist, :part => 'snippet'}
    puts playlistitems_response.data.items.count    
    if !playlistitems_response.data.items.count.eql? 0
        playlistitems_response.data.items.each do |video|
            puts "Video "+video['snippet']['title']+" published at: "+video['snippet']['publishedAt'].to_s
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Ruby sample from YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/ruby/my_uploads.rb) project. I don't think you are doing something wrong wrt API call. Either you are putting into a wrong playlist, or trying to list a playlist before the processing of the video finishes etc.

Comment: thanks for your response. How should I proceed to take the authorization code. Because in the url you sent me, in the samples, they call a tool from ruby code: #auth_util = CommandLineOAuthHelper.new(YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE)
#client.authorization = auth_util.authorize()
This launches the browser and gives me a code, but how should I use that code because when I run the script, it launches a server and blocks the process

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I've to specify the max_results parameter in the following way:

```
playlistitems = client.execute!(:api_method => youtube.playlist_items.list,
    :parameters => 
    {:playlistId => playlist, 
     :part => 'snippet',
     :maxResults => 50})
```